# Setting Shader via BGL

Tags: python

How to set up a shader in bgl ?

Thats what I've so far:

```
shaderVert = 0
shaderFrag = 0

shaderProgramVert = 0
shaderProgramFrag = 0

def __init__(self):

    if(self.__class__.shaderVert == 0 or self.__class__.shaderFrag == 0):
        bgl.glShaderSource(self.__class__.shaderVert, shaderVertString)
        bgl.glShaderSource(self.__class__.shaderFrag, shaderFragString)

        bgl.glCompileShader(self.__class__.shaderVert)
        bgl.glCompileShader(self.__class__.shaderFrag)

        self.__class__.shaderProgramVert = bgl.glCreateShader(bgl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        self.__class__.shaderProgramFrag = bgl.glCreateShader(bgl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        bgl.glAttachShader(self.__class__.shaderProgramVert, self.__class__.shaderVert)
        bgl.glAttachShader(self.__class__.shaderProgramFrag, self.__class__.shaderFrag)

        bgl.glLinkProgram(self.__class__.shaderProgramVert)
        bgl.glLinkProgram(self.__class__.shaderProgramFrag)

        print("Shader sucessfully compiled and linked")
```

#

```
    bgl.glUseProgram(self.__class__.shaderProgramVert)
    bgl.glUseProgram(self.__class__.shaderProgramFrag)
```

But how can I set Uniforms in bgl ?
Didn't found anything...

Comment: noOne out there with any idea ?

Comment: [Geometry-Shader-using-OpenGL-Wrapper](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?362582-Geometry-Shader-using-OpenGL-Wrapper-%28bgl%29)  does that help? if it does please write out an answer that uses it, else I will.